# I'm having trouble saving scores from each difficulty level in my game and displaying them each in separate labels

Tags: ios, objective-c

In my GameScoreViewController, I have 3 labels to display scores for Easy, Medium and Hard levels. In my GameSettingsViewController, I have 3 buttons for level difficulty; Easy, Medium and Hard (level difficulty is already coded and working). In my GameViewController, I have 1 label for the score. I'm having trouble / just need some guidance on the best way to get the score after the game ends from GameViewController back to the GameScoreViewController in the right score label based on difficulty that was played (easy, medium, hard).

I'm still fairly new to objective-c. Everything to this point is coded except for this piece.

I had this working fine when it was just one score, one label.

**I warn you, my code for this is redundant and could definitely use some refactoring, so any tips would be greatly appreciated.**

GameScoreViewController.h

```
NSInteger highScoreEasy;
NSInteger highScoreMedium;
NSInteger highScoreHard;
```

GameScoreViewController.m

```
highScoreEasy = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] integerForKey:@"highScoreEasySaved"];
highScoreEasyLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@" %li", (long)highScoreEasy];

highScoreMedium = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] integerForKey:@"highScoreMediumSaved"];
highScoreMediumLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@" %li", (long)highScoreMedium];

highScoreHard = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] integerForKey:@"highScoreHardSaved"];
highScoreHardLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@" %li", (long)highScoreHard];
```

I don't have any specific code for this in the GameSettingsViewController.h other than the difficulty buttons, but I'll show the code anyways. FYI, I'm using NSObject to set and get the difficulty.

GameSettingsViewController.h

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UIButton *easyModeButton;
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UIButton *mediumModeButton;
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UIButton *hardModeButton;

-(IBAction)easyMode;
-(IBAction)mediumMode;
-(IBAction)hardMode;
```

GameSettingsViewController.m

```
-(IBAction)easyButton {
[GameManager setDifficulty:0];
highScoreEasy = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] integerForKey:@"highScoreEasySaved"];
}

-(IBAction)mediumButton {
[GameManager setDifficulty:1];
highScoreMedium = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] integerForKey:@"highScoreMediumSaved"];
}

-(IBAction)hardButton {
[GameManager setDifficulty:2];
highScoreHard = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] integerForKey:@"highScoreHardSaved"];
}
```

GameViewController.h

```
int scoreEasy;
int scoreMedium;
int scoreHard;

IBOutlet UILabel *scoreEasyLabel;
IBOutlet UILabel *scoreMediumLabel;
IBOutlet UILabel *scoreHardLabel;

-(void)scoreEasy;
-(void)scoreMedium;
-(void)scoreHard;
```

GameViewController.m

```
-(void)GameOver {

if (scoreEasy > highScoreEasy) {
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setInteger:scoreEasy forKey:@"highScoreEasySaved"];
}
else if (scoreMedium > highScoreMedium) {
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setInteger:scoreMedium forKey:@"highScoreMediumSaved"];
}
else if (scoreHard > highScoreHard) {
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setInteger:scoreHard forKey:@"highScoreHardSaved"];
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
scoreEasy = 0;
highScoreEasy = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] integerForKey:@"highScoreEasySaved"];

scoreMedium = 0;
highScoreMedium = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] integerForKey:@"highScoreMediumSaved"];

scoreHard = 0;
highScoreHard = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] integerForKey:@"highScoreHardSaved"];
```

**Here's the code that sets the difficulty of the game based on Easy, Medium, or Hard. I haven't put any code in here, but feel like this is where it should go; or maybe in the GameOver method after the score has been set?**

```
-(void)placeObjects {

randomTopObjectPosition = arc4random() %350;  
randomTopObjectPosition = randomTopObjectPosition - 228; 

//Get's _difficulty value from NSObject GameManager

[GameManager getDifficulty];

if ([GameManager getDifficulty] == 0) {

    randomBottomObjectPosition = randomTopObjectPosition + 690; //EASY
        objectTop.center = CGPointMake(340, randomTopObjectPosition);
        objectBottom.center = CGPointMake(340, randomBottomObjectPosition);

} else if ([GameManager getDifficulty] == 1) {
    randomBottomObjectPosition = randomTopObjectPosition + 670; //MEDIUM
        objectTop.center = CGPointMake(340, randomTopObjectPosition);
        objectBottom.center = CGPointMake(340, randomBottomObjectPosition);

} else if ([GameManager getDifficulty] == 2) {
    randomBottomObjectPosition = randomTopObjectPosition + 655; //HARD
        objectTop.center = CGPointMake(340, randomTopObjectPosition);
        objectBottom.center = CGPointMake(340, randomBottomObjectPosition);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a few hours, I finally figured it out.  I had to update the GameOver method to also include the difficulty.

```
-(void)GameOver {

[GameManager getDifficulty]; //ADDED

if ([GameManager getDifficulty] == 0 & scoreEasy > highScoreEasy) {  //ADDED [GameManager getDifficulty] == 0
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setInteger:scoreEasy forKey:@"highScoreEasySaved"];
}

else if ([GameManager getDifficulty] == 1 & scoreMedium > highScoreMedium) { //ADDED [GameManager getDifficulty] == 1
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setInteger:scoreMedium forKey:@"highScoreMediumSaved"];
}
else if ([GameManager getDifficulty] == 2 & scoreHard > highScoreHard) { //ADDED [GameManager getDifficulty] == 2
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setInteger:scoreHard forKey:@"highScoreHardSaved"];
}
```